# Como salvar dados do Twitter, baixados no R, em Excel?

Tags: r, twitter-api

Estou usando o R para fazer o download de dados de perfis públicos no Twitter. A hora da coleta vai direitinho, com o seguinte código:

```
library(rtweet)

trump <- get_timelines("realDonaldTrump", n = 500)
```

O problema é que, quando vou salvar para excel, a separação das colunas fica toda errada (talvez porque uma delas contenha o texto do post). Já tentei usar a função `save` (em CSV e TXT) e também a "WriteXLS", além da "write.table" com outros separadores que não a vírgula (";" e "\t"), mas nada dá certo. Alguém sabe como fazer isso? No ambiente do R a tabela aparece direitinho.

Obrigada!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente com `writexl`

```
install.packages('writexl')  

library(writexl)

write_xlsx(x = trump, path = 'trump.xlsx')
```

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigada!!